# Is there a shortcut in Sequelize for "user.setGroups()" when I have all the group ids?

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize, if I have a simple parent-child relationship I can set the foreignKey column without the whole object:

```
Chapter.belongsTo(Book);

// this works, but I had to query the DB for the 'book' object
return Chapter.create({title: 'The Title'}).then(function(chapter) {
  return chapter.setBook(book);
}
```

The above generates two SQL statements, one to INSERT into the chapters table and one to UPDATE the foreignKey.

```
// this also works, if I happen to know the book ID already
return Chapter.create({
   title: 'The Title',
   bookId: 123
})
```

The above generates only one SQL statement that INSERTs the record with the foreign key already set.

Does anyone know of a "similar shorthand" to do that with many-to-many relations? E.g.

```
User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: 'UsersGroup' });
Group.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'UsersGroup' });

return User.create({
  name: 'John Doe',
  groupIds: [ 1, 2, 3 ] // does not work :(
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, brain malfunction. Turns out that I missed this bit of [documentation](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/associations/):

> You don't have to pass in a complete object to the association functions, if your associated model has a single primary key:
>
> ```
> user.addPicture(req.query.pid)
> // Here pid is just an integer, representing the primary key of the picture
> ```

So, I can't create everything in one call (of course, since I need to insert into another table), but I *can* avoid extra lookups by calling:

```
return User.create({name: 'John Doe'}).then(function(user) {
  return user.setGroups([1, 2, 3]);
})
```

Comment: you can actually do so via `user.setGroups([1,2,3], {save:false})`