# Node.js / Sequelize.js / Express.js - How to insert into many-to-many association? (sync/async?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I have two models (Individual, Email) and am trying to insert into the created 'Individual_Email' table using the Sequelize commands. While Sequelize is creating the desired table, it returns the following error when trying to add/get/set to/from that table: "Object [object Promise] has no method 'addEmail'". What am I missing?

The Sequelize documentation says if the models are User and Project, "This will add methods getUsers, setUsers, addUsers to Project, and getProjects, setProjects and addProject to User."

This leads me to believe (looking at promises) that I'm likely misunderstanding how to use the asynchronous features of Node. I've tried both a synchronous and async version of insertion, both returning the same message above.

Sequelize Documentation: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

Code:

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var models  = require('../models');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    'use strict';

    var tIndividual, tEmail;
    tIndividual = models.Individual.create({
        name: "Test"
    });
    tEmail = models.Email.create({
        address: "test@gmail.com"
    });
    console.log(tEmail);

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

OR

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    'use strict';

    var tIndividual, tEmail;    
    tIndividual = models.Individual.create({
        name: "Test"
    }).then(function(){
        tEmail = models.Email.create({
            address: "test@gmail.com"
        }).then(function(){
            tIndividual.addEmail(tEmail).then(function(){
                console.log("Success");
            });
        })
    });

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**models/index.js**

```
db.Individual.hasMany(db.Email, {
    as: 'Email',
    through: 'Individual_Email'
});
db.Email.hasMany(db.Individual, {
    as: 'Individual',
    through: 'Individual_Email'
});
```

How can I add to the table 'Individual_Email' in the best way? I'm assuming I need to do it synchronously to wait for the update, but I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `.save()` or `.create()` or other methods that return a Promise, you should call `.then()` on that promise. When it resolves -- that is, when the object gets saved/created/something-elsed -- your `then` function will be called, and will receive the saved/created object as a parameter.

So your first attempt could be rewritten as:

```
models.Individual.create({
  name: "Test"
}).then(function(createdIndividual) { // note the argument
  models.Email.create({
    address: "test@gmail.com"
  }).then(function(createdEmail) { // note the argument
    createdIndividual.addEmail(createdEmail)
      .then(function(addedEmail) { // note th-- well you get the idea :)
        console.log("Success");
      });
  })
});
```

The above code lacks a few important things, such as `return`ing the promises for better chaining and error handling, but it's a start. I'd recommend [Bluebird's documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) on the matter (that's the Promise library that Sequelize uses, but there are several others)

Comment: Can you add the while the Email is being created in one shot? instead of first create then addEmail?

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia Note that this association is N:M, since both the Individual and the Email have been configured with `hasMany`. So there are three tables in the end (Emails, Individuals, and EmailIndividual). The above code will, in practice, generate three INSERT statements, and you can't get less than that because there are three tables to populate.

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia That said, I once had a similar situation that I solved in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751483/is-there-a-shortcut-in-sequelize-for-user-setgroups-when-i-have-all-the-grou

Answer (score 2):

You can mitigate the "**[Pyramid of Doom](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/)**" using promises of the best way:

```
var createdIndividual;
models.Individual.create({
  name: "Test"
}).then(function(createdIn) { // note the argument
  createdIndividual = createdIn;
  return models.Email.create({
    address: "test@gmail.com"
  });
}).then(function(createdEmail) { // note the argument
  return createdIndividual.addEmail(createdEmail);
}).then(function(addedEmail) { // note th-- well you get the idea :)
  console.log("Success");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve it in one way, but let me know if there's a better way.

My solution:
Since .create() returned a promise, I instead used .build() which returned an instance, and only added to 'Individual_Email' after both had been saved synchronously. I then called the add method on the instance returned from .build() and inserted into the table.

My code:

```
var tIndividual, tEmail;
tIndividual = models.Individual.build({
    name: "Test"
});
tEmail = models.Email.build({
    address: 'test@gmail.com'
});
tIndividual.save()
    .success(function(){
        tEmail.save()
        .success(function(){
            tIndividual.addEmail(tEmail);
        });
});
```

Comment: It's probably bette to chain the thens instead of nesting them for no reasons.

Comment: Hey Can you addEmail while you are building the object, before it is actually created?

The reason I ask is I wan to make sure if whole insert succeeds go for it otherwise don't even bother creating anything in any table